# Problem with sizePerPage changing in pagination for react BootstrapTable

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I want to have pagination for my BootstrapTable. when I change my size per page, instead of showing a table with another size,it redirects me to my home page!

this occurred to me when I used remote option for my pagination.

```
    render() {
       const options = {
         onPageChange: this.handlePageChange,
         page: this.state.page,
         totalSize:this.state.totalSize,
         onSizePerPageList: this.handleSizePerPageChange,
         sizePerPage: this.state.sizePerPage
    };  

  <BootstrapTable
                  keyField='id'
                  data={this.state.item}
                  columns={ this.props.columns}
                  pagination={ paginationFactory(options) }
                  remote/>
}
```